# Contourf not showing full range of values

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

I have two datasets that when compared result in a basically random distribution of values between -1 and 1. When I plot this using contourf, however, the figure shows almost all values > 0.5. When I plot every 10th point (thin the data), I get a graph that is more reasonable. But it is not clear why the contourf function is doing this.

I replicated this using a random number list of the same size as my data. The result is the same.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import numpy as np

random = np.random.random((360,1600))*2.-1.

f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))

#heights = ax.contour(to_np(hgt),3,colors='k')
#ax.clabel(heights, fmt='%2.0f', colors='k', fontsize=8)
#cbar = f.colorbar(heights)
#heights.levels=[0,100,3000]
#plt.clabel(heights, heights.levels)

clevs = [-0.5,-0.1,0.1,0.5]
diffplot = ax[0].contourf(random[::10,::10],clevs,extend='both')

cbar = f.colorbar(diffplot,ax=ax[0])

clevs = [-0.5,-0.1,0.1,0.5]
diffplot2 = ax[1].contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both')

cbar = f.colorbar(diffplot2,ax=ax[1])
```

[Result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgRlj.png)

Comment: Found a solution by the figure dpi setting, and added it to the answer (previously only having the explanation).

Answer (score 0):

The full range is shown, but **the issue is in the large number of points vs. resolution.**

That means points drawn 'later' (aka the ones at the end of the color levels range = higher values) have a certain minimum size (you still need to see them) that then overlaps previous (aka smaller values) points, resulting in the image colors looking skewed.

---

**Solution** is to increase the dpi of the figure (matplotlib default is 100dpi):

Note how the reduced points from your example plotted on the left hand side looks the same but the right hand side only looks similar >=300 dpi.

[image]

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import numpy as np

random = np.random.random((360,1600))*2.-1.
clevs = [-0.5,-0.1,0.1,0.5]

f1, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))  # ,dpi=100
diffplot = ax[0].contourf(random[::10,::10],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f1.colorbar(diffplot,ax=ax[0])
diffplot2 = ax[1].contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f1.colorbar(diffplot2,ax=ax[1])
f1.set_dpi(100)
f1.suptitle('dpi = 100', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 20)


f2, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))  # ,dpi=150
diffplot = ax[0].contourf(random[::10,::10],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f2.colorbar(diffplot,ax=ax[0])
diffplot2 = ax[1].contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f2.colorbar(diffplot2,ax=ax[1])
f2.set_dpi(150)
f2.suptitle('dpi = 150', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 20)


f3, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))  # ,dpi=300
diffplot = ax[0].contourf(random[::10,::10],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f3.colorbar(diffplot,ax=ax[0])
diffplot2 = ax[1].contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f3.colorbar(diffplot2,ax=ax[1])
f3.set_dpi(300)
f3.suptitle('dpi = 300', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 20)


f4, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))  # ,dpi=600
diffplot = ax[0].contourf(random[::10,::10],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f4.colorbar(diffplot,ax=ax[0])
diffplot2 = ax[1].contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f4.colorbar(diffplot2,ax=ax[1])
f4.set_dpi(600)
f4.suptitle('dpi = 600', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 20)


f5, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))  # ,dpi=900
diffplot = ax[0].contourf(random[::10,::10],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f5.colorbar(diffplot,ax=ax[0])
diffplot2 = ax[1].contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both')
cbar = f5.colorbar(diffplot2,ax=ax[1])
f5.set_dpi(900)
f5.suptitle('dpi = 900', fontweight = 'bold', fontsize = 20)

plt.show()
```

Note the two options for setting the dpi:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5), dpi=600)
# or 
fig.set_dpi(600)
```

---

An explanation from another angle - **bare with me for some plots**:

Note: The following plots are arranged with `gridspec` to be shown in a single figure.
That way the 'resolution' is depicted in a comparable way.

**1) The effect you recognized depends on the plot size**

See the code below, all 3 plots contain the same data ..., the only difference is their size.
Notice how with the increased size the colors distribution looks more and more as expected.

[image]

```
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


random = np.random.random((360,1600))*2.-1.
#random = np.random.random((100,100))*2.-1.

clevs = [-0.5,-0.1,0.1,0.5]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,20), facecolor=(1, 1, 1))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 4, height_ratios=[1,1,4]) 

cmap='viridis'  # Note: 'viridis' is the default cmap


ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:1])
ax1.set_title('ax1')
diffplot1 = ax1.contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both', cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(diffplot1, ax=ax1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2,2:])
ax2.set_title('ax2')
diffplot2 = ax2.contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both', cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(diffplot2, ax=ax2)
    
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,:])
ax3.set_title('ax3')
diffplot3 = ax3.contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both', cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(diffplot3, ax=ax3)


fig.tight_layout() 
# plt.savefig("Contourf_Colorbar.png")
plt.show()
```

**2) The effect you recognized depends on number of points 'cramped' into a plot**

Basically the same that you've already noticed in your question with plotting only every 10th value.
Notice how the colors distribution looks as expected kinda the same for the 3 plot sizes.

[image]

Activate `random = np.random.random((100,100))*2.-1.` in the code block above to get this plot.

**3) Reversed color cmap as another way of showing the effect**

Notice how this is like the plot from 1) but just with reversed colors.

[image]

```
from matplotlib import gridspec
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


random = np.random.random((360,1600))*2.-1.
clevs = [-0.5,-0.1,0.1,0.5]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,20), facecolor=(1, 1, 1))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 4, height_ratios=[1,1,4]) 

# reverse cmap
cmap='viridis'  # Note: 'viridis' is the default cmap
cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)
cmap = cmap.reversed()
    

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:1])
ax1.set_title('ax1')
diffplot1 = ax1.contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both', cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(diffplot1, ax=ax1)
    
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2,2:])
ax2.set_title('ax2')
diffplot2 = ax2.contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both', cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(diffplot2, ax=ax2)
    
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,:])
ax3.set_title('ax3')
diffplot3 = ax3.contourf(random[:,:],clevs,extend='both', cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(diffplot3, ax=ax3)


fig.tight_layout() 
# plt.savefig("Contourf_Colorbar_reverse.png")
plt.show()
```

---

Finally for reference from [`matplotlib contourf docu`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html):

> algorithm{'mpl2005', 'mpl2014', 'serial', 'threaded'}, optional
>
> Which contouring algorithm to use to calculate the contour lines and polygons. The algorithms are implemented in ContourPy, consult the
> ContourPy documentation for further information.
>
> The default is taken from rcParams["contour.algorithm"] (default: 'mpl2014').

I've tried some options (wasn't able to get `algorithm` going, but checked `antialiased` ... actually more in a try&error method) without an improvement.

But you could look into the referenced [`ContourPy`](https://contourpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.5/index.html) to maybe find a way to reduce the 'size of the dots' that are drawn, but that's out of my league.